# configurable product is out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9

configurable products are invisible in frontend (out of stock) until I click Catalog > Manage Products > "my configurable product" > save. What may be the reason? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do re-indexing if you are missing it after you save the product. Another reason can be that any of the associated product is out of stock or has qty as 0.